# Which material is a heat source for the other three materials?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy

Presented is a closed energy system containing equal masses of iron (55 degrees C), basalt (45 degrees C), and water (20 degrees C); air is 30 degrees C.

Which material is a heat source for the other three materials? 
**1) iron 2) basalt 3) air 4) water**
- Is the answer iron because it has the most heat?

During the first hour, the total energy in the system will 
**1) decrease, only
2) increase, only
3) decrease, then increase
4) remain the same**
- (Shouldn't it remain the same because of the conservation of energy?)

Also during the first hour, the temperature of the water will
**1) decrease
2) increase
3) remain the same**
- (I think it will increase because it acts as a heat sink? Or maybe it will remain the same because water has the highest specific heat?)

Helping me understand **one** or all of these would be a great help!

Comment: Answering these homework questions is against community rules, but as u r new, I'm answering. See the site:  https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my knowledge extends,

1st Question: 1. Iron (reason you've given).

2nd Question: 4. Remains same (Law of Conservation of Energy)

3rd Question: 2. Increases, as the system will try to reach a proper equilibrium at a fixed temperature, given by the Principle of Calorimetry.

Comment: [the Homework-and-exercises tag info page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) says you ought to focus on the method of getting the answer rather than providing the answer. Also I don't think the explanation for Q1 is using the right words.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to go about focusing on the method other than what I put in parenthesis. We are allowed to work together on these problems with a partner but I do not have any friends like everyone else in the class and the professor does not respond to emails; I don't know how else to go about solidifying these concepts...

Comment: Actually I'm just going to delete my account, I have given up lol. Thank you both of you for your help but I don't think I am what this community wants, thank you again.